# Ubuntu 11.10: how to add command line parameters to application icon

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I'm running the new Ubuntu 11.10 in VMWare and it is my first time using Unity. I've managed to drag the Terminal icon to the "dock" at the left side of the screen. When clicking on it, the terminal occurs too small. In previous Ubuntu versions with Gnome I right-clicked the icon and added the command line parameters `--geometry=120x40`. How can I do that with Unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the Terminal, you can set default size in *Edit - Profile Preferences*.

A general answer, though, is to find the program's `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` (in your case it's `gnome-terminal.desktop`), copy it<sup>1</sup> to `~/.local/share/applications/`<sup>2</sup>, and edit the "`Exec=...`" line according to your needs. You may need to restart Unity.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, copy it. ***COPY*** it. Do not just edit the original. The original will be replaced on every upgrade of that program.

<sup>2</sup> If the directory doesn't exist, create it.

Comment: How do you do that globally, I.e. not just for me?